# How do I get the list of projects using the Azure DevOps Python API?

Tags: python, azure-devops, azure-devops-rest-api

I'm trying to list out the project list from Azure devops Organization. I'm using python, following https://github.com/Microsoft/azure-devops-python-api

Here is my script

```
from vsts.vss_connection import VssConnection
from msrest.authentication import BasicAuthentication
import pprint

token = "Access token"
Azure_url = "https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/"

Credentials = BasicAuthentication("", token)
connection = VssConnection(base_url=Azure_url, creds=Credentials)

core_client = connection.get_client('vsts.core.v4_0.core_client.CoreClient')

projects = core_client.get_projects()
```

The output i'm getting

```
[<vsts.core.v4_0.models.team_project_reference.TeamProjectReference object at 00txgccbdffff>]
```

Is their a way to get list of projects in Json format?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is their a way to get list of projects in Json format.

Yes, please have a try to use the following code to convert the list of projects to json string.

```
import json
json_string = json.dumps([ob.__dict__ for ob in projects])
pprint.pprint(json_string)
```

Comment: Where can I find CoreClient  object attribute's .. I want to get the list of repositories in projects and I need to create a new repo by using these Rest Services is it possible .

Comment: @kotnav01 I recommend that you could look into the python API source code. If you want to create or list repositories. You could look into  [this link](https://github.com/Microsoft/azure-devops-python-api/blob/dev/vsts/vsts/git/v4_0/git_client_base.py#L2576) it is under the git_client_base. Glad to know my answer is helpful, you could [accept it as an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) to help more communities who have the same issue.  By the way, it is another question, I recommend that you post another SO thread that you could get more help for global communities.